# can't save data which has type 'date' to database

Tags: php, database

I want to save data which has type 'date', but when I click 'save', nothing happens.
is there something wrong?

```
<?php
include_once"connect.php";
?>
<input type="date" name="tanggal" id="tanggal"/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="simpan" value="Simpan"/>

<?php
$date=isset($_POST["tanggal"])?$_POST["tanggal"]:"";
$tanggal=date('dd-mm-yyyy', strtotime($date));
$simpan=isset($_POST["save"])?$_POST["save"]:"";
if($simpan!=""){
    $saving=mysql_query("insert into date values ('$tanggal')");
    if($saving){
    echo"<script>alert('Succed')</script>";
        echo"<script>location.href='?h=date.php'</script>";
    }else{
        echo"<script>alert('Failed')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The default date format is **YYYY-MM-DD**.

Comment: It should be $tanggal=date('yyyy-mm-dd', strtotime($date)); and also make sure you are getting $date value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use date format like yyyy-mm-dd

```
$date = isset($_POST["tanggal"])?$_POST["tanggal"]:"";
$tanggal = date('yyyy-mm-dd', strtotime($date));
$simpan = isset($_POST["save"])?$_POST["save"]:"";
if($simpan!=""){
    $saving = mysql_query("insert into date values ('$tanggal')");
    if($saving){
       echo"<script>alert('Succed')</script>";
       echo"<script>location.href='?h=date.php'</script>";
    }else{
       echo"<script>alert('Failed')</script>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line and it will save

```
$tanggal=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Database accept date in **YYYY-MM-DD** format.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$tanggal=date('dd-mm-yyyy', strtotime($date));
```

into

```
$tanggal=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```